# multiple toggle hide divs withought unhiding already hidden

Tags: javascript

I am trying to toggle some `div`s’ visibility with some buttons. I have two buttons that toggle different elements. Currently when you press the toggle button it will hide the `div`s but when you press the second button, it will toggle the visibility of its `div`s, and the other `div`s that are sharing the same class/ID (thus un-hiding them).

Example (also in [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g912c1d0/8/)):

```js
document.querySelector(".a").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
document.querySelector(".b").addEventListener("click", myFunction);


function myFunction() {
  let id = document.querySelectorAll(this.getAttribute('data-stuff'));

  for (let i = 0, len = id.length; i < len; i++) {

    console.log(id[i]);
    if (id[i].style.visibility == "collapse") {
      id[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      id[i].style.visibility = "collapse";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="stuff1">hi</div>
<div>hi</div>
<div id="stuff2">hi</div>
<div id="stuff1" class="stuff">hi</div>
<div id="stuff1">hi</div>
<div id="stuff1" class="stuff">hi</div>
<div>hi</div>

<input type="button" class="a" data-stuff="#stuff1" value="hide 1"><br>
<input type="button" class="b" data-stuff=".stuff" value="hide 2">
```

I know I have to check if the `div` is already hidden and if the second button is clicked, but I’m not sure how I would do that. I was going for something like this, but it didn’t work the way I wanted:

```js
let id = document.querySelectorAll(a);
let btn = document.querySelector('.a2').value;

for (let i = 0, len = id.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (id[i].style.visibility == "collapse") {
    if (id[i].style.visibility == "collapse" && /Show/i.test(btn)) {
      id[i].style.visibility = "collapse";
    }

    id[i].style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    id[i].style.visibility = "collapse";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition about how to check if the `div` is already hidden is correct. Sometimes you are forced to write an ugly if-else block for what seems like a simple function. But looking at your code I have some other comments that might help with your project.

First, the `id` attribute should be unique for every element i.e. no two elements should have the same `id`. There's nothing about html that enforces this, but it just leads to problems. On the other hand, elements are allowed to have multiple `class`es. I would suggest a `stuff1` class that's applied to all `div`s affected by one button and a `stuff2` class that's applied to all `div`s affected by the other. Some `div`s may get both classes and that's totally fine.

Second, I'd recommend using another library to select and manipulate elements on the page instead of using `document.querySelector()`, etc.  [jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/) is a good place to get started. [D3](https://d3js.org/) has a good interface as well and provides a lot more functionality!

Comment: You are completely right that it would be better to use `class`es than a duplicated `id`. But I don't see what is wrong with using functions like `document.querySelector` instead of jQuery. I know jQuery used to be necessary to avoid cross-browser incompatibilities, but I thought those were mostly straightened out by now. And a page without a library will take slightly less time to download. Can you elaborate on why you recommend a library?

Comment: Download speed has also improved so the cost of getting an extra script is not fatal for many applications. The benefit is you have to write less code and your code is easier to read for other people, which are important for productivity. But if a few ms delay on your page load is a deal breaker, by all means leave out external dependencies. It all depends on your situation. There's no one right solution.